# How to call several methods with JSF <f:ajax listener?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, java-ee-5

Good Afternoon,

I have a search page that uses ajax to render a **several datatables** without refreshing the page.
It is mandatory for me to call a Method as a Listener for each table.
Below is the snippet for the first datatable that works fine.

To render a second datatable I need to call a method `#{evalController.prepareList}` as a Listener for the ajax. The problem is that `<f:ajax` **"Listener"** attribute won't take **more than one method**.

So the remaining way is to call `<f:ajax` several times, and each time with a different listener, which does not work. Is there a way to achieve this?
If not, should I create a method in the managed Bean that calls all the methods that I need and use it as the one listener? 
*Thanks in advance for your help.*

```
<h:form id="searchform">

                <h:panelGrid columns="3" >
                    <p:inputText value="#{ddnController.patientID}" id="pidinput"   maxlength="7" size="7">
                        <f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="searchbutton ddntable" listener="#{ddnController.prepareList}"/>

                    </p:inputText>

                    <h:commandButton  image="#{resource['images/search.png']}" id="searchbutton" value="#{bundle.Search}" 
                                      action="submit" actionListener="#{ddnController.prepareList}" 
                                      disabled="#{empty ddnController.patientID or ddnController.patientID.equals('0')}"/>
                    <p:panel><h:outputText value="Saisir 0 pour avoir tous les Patients" style="font-style: italic;"/></p:panel>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:dataTable id="ddntable" value="#{ddnController.items}" var="ddn" rendered="#{!empty ddnController.items}" paginator="true" >....
```

Comment: what about using a composite function that calls multiple other functions within it.

Comment: So obvious I _almost_ didn't vote up your comment.

Comment: @Marcos @Steve Taylor  Thank you for your comments. The reason I asked this question is that I wanted to make sure there is no way doing it only in the view without swimming in the managed bean.

My issue actually is that I indeed created a method (function) that calls all the other functions I need to be called during ajax event and used as the ajax listener:   
`public void prepareAllLists(ActionEvent event){
ddnController = new DdnController();
ddnController.prepareList(); 
evalController = new....
evalController.prepareList();
......
}` But it does not work although it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure why the composite method do not have effect when called. Probably it is not called during before or after the right phase (I'll be profiling it later). Anyway, I found a solution with **two edges** (it is **solving my problem** but makes me **sacrifice the use of ajax**) :

So Instead of calling - from each managed bean - the method (prepareList()) which I use as listener:

```
   private DataModel items = null; // Getter to retrieve items
    // ......
    public String prepareList() {
    recreatemodel();
    return "List";
    } 
private void recreatemodel(){
items=null;
}
```

(by the way, this method sets the datamodel to `NULL` to refresh it, and that is how my datatables get refreshed).
Inside the command button I nested property action listener:

```
<h:commandButton image="#{resource['images/search.png']}" id="searchbutton" value="#{bundle.Search}" 
                                      action="submit" 
                                      disabled="#{empty ddnController.patientID or ddnController.patientID.equals('0')}">

<f:PropertyActionListener target="#{ddnController.items}" value="#{null}" />
<f:PropertyActionListener target="#{evalController.items}" value="#{null}" />
<f:PropertyActionListener target="#{corController.items}" value="#{null}" />
<!--...etc -->

</h:commandButton>
```

I wish `<f:PropertyActionListener />` could be nested inside `<h:ajax/>.`

If somebody has a solution that allows to use **property action listener** and **ajax** to avoid submitting the form with a button, s/he is welcome. I'll make then his/her answer as accepted.

Comment: @Marcos @Steve Taylor If somebody has a solution that allows to use property action listener and ajax to avoid submitting the form with a button, s/he is welcome. I'll make then his/her answer as accepted.